# Vuex toggle array item boolean value

Tags: vue.js, vuex

For some reason I can not find a working solution to toggle checkbox of an item from Vuex state array. I got it working to a point where I am able to display todo items, but whenever I try to commit and call a toggle mutation, it doesn't work as expected, nothing changes.
If I set done = true, it works, but not toggling it. Any idea?

View:

```
<template>
  <div class="todos">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="todo in $store.state.todos" :key="todo.id">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="todo.done"
          @change="$store.commit('toggle', todo.id)"
        />
        <h3>{{ todo.title }}</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({});
</script>

<style></style>
```

State:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import Todo from '@/types/Todo';
import { State } from 'vue';

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      todos: [] as Todo[],
    };
  },
  mutations: {
    add(state: State, todo: Todo) {
      state.todos.push(todo);
    },
    toggle(state: State, todoId: number) {
      const index = state.todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === todoId);
      state.todos[index].done = !state.todos[index].done;
    },
  },
});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the memory reference of the todos array by cloning the `state.todos` array and deconstructing the todo object.

```
state.todos = state.todos.map((todo) => ({...todo, done: todoId === todo.id ? !todo.done : todo.done }));
```

Comment: Seems to be no difference.

Comment: @ŽanFras I edited, maybe because the todo was an object as well it should update its memory reference.

Comment: Ur welcome, by the way I think the `v-model` is not necesary since you are updating the value in the store and not in the component, `v-model` tries to update the value. It should work just by adding `value="todo.done"` and the `@change` should do the trick.